# Java Controller and Service - Implement Getter and Setter in Service

Tags: java, spring

I have the following controller and Service class,

> UserController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/getUser")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getUser(@ModelAttribute UserRequestModel userRequest, HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    final IContext context = contextFactory.getContext(request);
    Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();

    String UserID = userService.getUserID(context, userRequest.getName());

    if (UserID != null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userService.getUserDetails(context, userID);
        ...
    }

    ...

 return responseMap;
}

------
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/Booking")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> Booking(@RequestParam("bookingRequest") String RequestAsJSON,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();

    final IContext context = contextFactory.getContext(request);
    UserList userList = userService.getUserList(context, RequestAsJSON);
    IUserResponse userresponse = userService.createBooking(RequestAsJSON, context, userList);
    return responseMap;
}
```

Also following Service class,

> `UserService.java`:

```
@Override
public String getUserID(IContext requestContext, String userName) {
   String userID = null;
   List<User> users = createUser(context, userName);
   userID = <API>.getID(context, userList);
   return userID;
}

@Override
public UserDetails getUserDetails(IContext context, String userID) {
   UserDetails userDetails = null;
   userDetails = <API>.getUserDetails(userID, context);
   return userDetails;
}

@Override
public UserList getUserList(IContext context, String requestAsJSON) {
    JsonObject requestObj = new JsonParser().parse(requestAsJSON).getAsJsonObject();
    String userName = requestObj.get("Name").getAsString();
    UserCard userCard = createCard(userName);
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(userCard);
    UserList userList = new UserList();
    userList.setUsers(users);
    ..

    return userList;
}
    ....
private List<User> createUser(IContext context, String userName) {
   List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
   UserCard userCard = createCard(userName);
   users.add(userCard);
   return users;
}

private UserCard createCard(String userName) {
   UserCard userCard = new UserCard();
   userCard.setOfficeID(12345);
   userCard.setAddress("Addr1");
   userCard.setOffice(“Test”);
   return userCard;
}
```

Currently `createCard` method is calling twice when getting user ("/user/getUser") and booking ("/user/Booking").

I would like to `createCard` while "/user/getUser" and get this card while "/user/Booking". I would like to get help in creating getter and setter.

Comment: I would not recommend to create a setter for ``UserCard`` object because you cannot be sure, that REST API will be called in a certain order like ``/user/getUser`` at first and ``/user/Booking`` after that. I'd suggest to pass whole ``User`` or ``UserCard`` objects to the ``/user/Booking`` as a request payload. Second problem with using setter is the fact, that you will not be able to predict how many times ``/user/getUser`` method will be called before ``/user/Booking``, so your user in fact can be updated before you will use it.

Comment: I think there's also a scope to use cache, with expiry, will it not fit for your case?

Answer (score 1):

In your service you might use a `Map` to store the `name` and `userCard` as key-value pairs:

```
static Map<String , UserCard> userCardInfo = new HashMap<>();

//inside createUser populate it

private List<User> createUser(IContext context, String userName) {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    UserCard userCard = createCard(userName);
    users.add(userCard);
    this.userCardInfo.put(userName , userCard);
    return users;
}

//and inside getUserList retrieve from that map

public UserList getUserList(IContext context, String requestAsJSON) {
    JsonObject requestObj = new JsonParser().parse(requestAsJSON).getAsJsonObject();
    String userName = requestObj.get("Name").getAsString();
    UserCard userCard = null;
    if(this.userCardInfo.containsKey(userName)) {
        userCard = this.userCardInfo.get(userName);
    } else {
        userCard = createCard(userName);
    }

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(userCard);
    UserList userList = new UserList();
    userList.setUsers(users);
    return userList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This two are separate request. **REST** is stateless so how can you do it ? Best Option can be You can pass data to client end that are you created on first request. And then for **second Request** Your client will serve this data with **requestbody**. You can put data on a static variable but its not a good practice.

You can do like this :

```
if (UserID != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.getUserDetails(context, userID);
            responseMap.put("userDetails",userDetails);
        }
```

And when call from client end then client should **add usercard data to request**. build a request that will accept **usercardata** on **request** object. May be your code already doing this.

Comment: need to retrieve from responseMap?

Comment: yes. If you want to keep hashmap as return type then you can put card data on hashMap during first request

Comment: set responseMap and passing it like: 
IUserResponse userresponse = userService.createBooking(RequestAsJSON, context, requestMap);    I hope, this is the correct way and will work.

Comment: can you share your BookingService .createBooking method? Then I can tell what you need to update

Comment: @Override
    public IUserResponse createBooking(String RequestAsJSON, IContext context, UserList userList, Map<String, Object> responseMap) throws IOException {
  
        IUserResponse userResponse = responseService.book(RequestAsJSON,context, userList, responseMap);
        return userResponse;
    }

Comment: is RequestAsJSON and responseMap behaves as same?

Comment: When you returning response map its converted as JSON Array by converter that you are using. So client can parse your responseMap and build RequestAsJSON data with your necessary data as RequestAsJSON field. you don't need to accept extra parameter responseMap with request. But its upto you you can send both or you can send with same parameter.